# How can I force only GD output with PHP?

Tags: php, gd, shared-hosting

I am working on a PHP project using the GD library to output a GIF image directly to the page. I know how to use GD, and I've gotten the image to save to a file correctly, the problem is that my hosting server appends a string to the end of all output, even if I use `die()` or `exit()`, therefore any non-html output doesn't work. I'm just trying to output an image, which won't work if any other data is outputted.

Comment: Show some code. Are you setting the appropriate headers for the image?

Comment: header("Content-type: image/gif");

Answer (score 3):

Get a real web host. We cannot override the entity with control over the server environment.

Comment: It's an Apache server, with .htaccess file support, could this make any difference?

Comment: Doubtful. Get a real web host.